# Apache camel exchange setbody some properties missing

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I get a xml request from apache camel route. I validate this request in my validator and make changes to the request properties as required but when I set the same request as setBody() those properties missing from xml.

Code to get request

```
MyCustomRequest request = ex.getIn().getBody(MyCustomRequest .class);
```

Code to set request after modification
ex.getIn().setBody(request );

Validation code

```
 Iterator<ConstraintViolation<AbstractEvent>> itr = fieldValidationWarning.iterator();
        String[] propertyPathArray = null;
        String propertyPath = "";
        PropertyAccessor myAccessor = null;
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            ConstraintViolation<AbstractEvent> warning = itr.next();
            propertyPath = warning.getPropertyPath().toString();
            propertyPathArray = propertyPath.split("\\.");
```

if (!propertyPathArray[1].contains("person")) {
PropertyAccessor myAccessor = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(request.getName());
myAccessor.setPropertyValue(propertyPathArray[propertyPathArray.length - 1], null);
}

Now my problem is when I see the xml in queue I can not see . It disappears somehow.

Also if I don't change my request the end xml has tags like `<v1:BookingEventRequest> and if I change any property using PropertyAccessorFactory then tags become <ns3:BookingEventRequest>`

Exchnage out code

```
ex.setProperty(Exchange.FILTER_NON_XML_CHARS, Boolean.TRUE);
    ex.getOut().setBody(request);
    ex.getOut().setHeaders(ex.getIn().getHeaders());
    String messageId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    MDC.put("correlationId", messageId);
    ex.getOut().setHeader(MDC_KEY_MESSAGE_ID, messageId);
    ex.setProperty(RouteConstants.VALIDATION_DETAIL_PROP_ATTR_NAME, returnCodeType);
    ex.setProperty(RouteConstants.IS_VALID_REQ_PROP_ATTR_NAME, returnCodeType.getType() == ReturnType.SUCCESS);
```

Comment: Can you add your validator code?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai code has been added. I can not add the complete code because of copyright issue but it's just validating using custom annotations and if any specific error occur then I rest the property to null.

Comment: Actually I wanted to see the camel processor that is calling your custom validator incase you are doing something with `ex.getOut()`

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai Added exhange getOut code

Comment: I think you have to make sure `ex.getOut().setBody(request);` this contains the modified request.

Comment: I am making modifications to the same request object which I get from getBody() and later setting the same request object as setBody()